# NSInternalInconsistencyException when registering to a pure channel on parse

Tags: ios, parse-framework

I amusing Parse and calling:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)newDeviceToken
{
    [PFPush storeDeviceToken:newDeviceToken];
    [PFPush subscribeToChannelInBackground:@"" target:self selector:@selector(subscribeFinished:error:)];
}
```

Then when lunching the app I a getting this error:

> 2012-06-30 00:13:23.380 JerusalemBiblicalZoo[607:707] *** Terminating
>   app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
>   reason: 'Can't subscribe to a channel when the current installation
>   object is dirty.'

I have disabled  this line:

```
 [PFPush subscribeToChannelInBackground:@"" target:self selector:@selector(subscribeFinished:error:)];
```

And it works great.

Any ideas hoe too fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rolled back to an earlier version and all is well. I'm only getting that error with the newest release.

Comment: Where did you downloaded the older version from

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. I checked their site and I cannot locate their archive of previous releases, sorry. Luckily, I had an older version of their SDK saved locally.

I tried their newest release as of today and it is now crashing my app on load. Hmpft.

Were you able to sort out your issue?

Comment: Hey, thanks but they just replied my bug report. They said it is fixed now and there is a new release. I will check it out and report.